# Is complex surface in CP(3) a two handlebody?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, intersection-theory, 4-manifolds, handle-decomposition

Consider a complex surface given by homogeneous equation in $\mathbb{C}P^3$. Without loss of generality, take

\begin{equation}
S = \{[x:y:z:w] \in \mathbb{C}P^3~ |~ x^d + y^d + z^d + w^d = 0\}
\end{equation}

It is well known this surface is simply connected. We may compute the intersection form depending on whether $d$ is  even or odd. My question is: is this surface admits handle decomposition with 2-handles only? If it is not, why?

More generally, given intersection form $Q$, if the 4-manifold is 2-handlebody, then the intersection form is represented by linking number of a link in $S^3$. However, given an intersection form and knowing that the 4-manifold is simply connected, can we deduce its handle decomposition?

Comment: If a 4-manifold is simply connected, it does not contain any 1-handle (which does not cancel with a 2-handle). Then it cannot contain any 3-handles either, otherwise by turning it upside down, you get a handle decomposition with 1-handles. So it merely consists of 0-, 2- and 4-handles.

Comment: @asdfasdfgasd Not exactly. I just found a paper by Mandelbaum, saying that the Rudolph's way of showing non-singular surface in CP3 does not have one handle cannot remove 3 handle simultaneously. And Kirby showed in 1976 that Kummer surface does not have both one and three handles.

Comment: @asdfasdfgasd Put it this way: simply connectedness does not necessarily imply that any handle decomposition does not have one handle or three handle. For example, S^2 has a handle decomposition with one handle, two 2-handles, and one zero handle, but it is still simply connected.

Comment: thanks for the comment, you may find these two sources helpful:http://www.math.msu.edu/~akbulut/papers/akbulut.lec.pdf. (section 12.2.1). Also  the introduction to this paper: http://www.math.msu.edu/~akbulut/papers/dolgachev1.pdf